# Why my do-it-myself Lasso gives different solution paths from the scikit-learn's lasso_path?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I tried [recreating Lasso from scratch in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-lasso-regression-from-scratch-using-python/) with some modifications to the Lasso class as below:

```py
class custom_lasso():

    def __init__(self, lr, iter, lamb):
        self.eta = lr
        self.max_iter = iter
        self.alpha = lamb

    # Function for model training

    def fit(self, X, Y):

        # no_of_training_examples, no_of_features
        self.n, self.p = X.shape
        # weight initialization
        self.B, self.X, self.Y = zeros(self.p), X, Y

        # gradient descent learning
        for i in range(self.max_iter):
            self.update_weights(i)

        return self

    # Helper function to update weights in gradient descent

    def update_weights(self, j):

        # calculate gradients
        dB = self.X.transpose() @ (self.X @ self.B - self.Y)
        if j:
            dB += abs(self.B)/self.B * self.alpha
        # update weights
        self.B -= self.eta * dB
        return self
```

given that I aim to minimize `0.5 sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - sum_{j=1}^p x_{ij} b_j)^2 + alpha * sum_{j=1}^p abs(b_j)` w.r.t. to all the `b_j`.

**Problem:** If I try to compare the solution paths with [scikit-learn's `lasso_path`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html), I found the resulting coefficients are quite different. For example, if I set n = 100, p = 5 and `alpha` = 1, then `lasso_path` gives `b_2` = 0 but the scratchy lasso I came up with gives `b_2` = 0.5962:

[image]

How come the differences? Any more codes I should include? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing gradient descent on the objective function, but the objective function is not smooth because of the L1 penalty.

I don't get why there's an `if` here (and it does not seem to be used in your code, meaning that you just solve ordinary least squares if eta is small enough):

```
        if j:
            dB += abs(self.B)/self.B * self.alpha
```

In order to obtain a converging solver, you need to apply **proximal** gradient descent, i.e. apply a soft-thresholding step after the gradient descent step:

```
gd_update = B - eta * X.T @ (X @ B - y)
B = np.maximum(0, np.abs(gd_update) - alpha * eta)
```

For it to converge, you need `eta < 2 / np.linalg.norm(X, ord=2)**2`, as for standard gradient descent.